# Why does setting fixed width not work in this case?

Tags: tables, booktabs

Why does this not work? I want to set each column to be `0.3\linewidth` but it's giving an error saying "runaway argument" and no PDF.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,capt-of}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[!t]
  \centering
  \caption{MY TABLE}
  \label{tab:table7}
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.3\linewidth}*{3}
                            \toprule
    No & A1& A2\\ \midrule
    1 &  Q3 & Q5         \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
%

\end{document}
```

Comment: `{p{0.3\linewidth}*{3}` has 3 `{` and 2 `}` possibly  `*3{p{0.3\linewidth}}`  ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `{p{0.2\linewidth}*{3}}` doesn't work either?

Comment: `*{3}{c}` would be ccc but you have not provided the second argument of `*`

Comment: If you want three `p` columns `0.3\textwidth` wide, it should be `*{3}{p{0.3\textwidth}}`

Comment: @egreg I tried that and the table is bigger but the text doesn't seem to be in the center of each column.

Comment: @internet Why should it be? In `p` columns the text is justified, so it starts from the far left of the cell. Please, specify more clearly what you would like to get.

Comment: @egreg I want to make three columns each of them has a width of `0.3\textwidth` and the text is center aligned in each column.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax would be

```
*{3}{p{0.3\textwidth}}
```

but you wouldn't get centering.

I don't really think you really want to spread the table like that, but it depends on the actual table entries.

With `array` you can use the `w{c}{<dimen>}` column type: fixed width `<dimen>` and centering (no automatic line breaks in cells).

The correct size can be obtained with arithmetic and not by guessing (and `0.3\textwidth` was a wrong guess).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\caption{MY TABLE}
\label{tab:table7}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{*{3}{w{c}{\dimexpr\textwidth/3-2\tabcolsep}}}
\toprule
No & A1& A2 \\
\midrule
1 &  Q3 & Q5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it works but the code looks scary!!

Comment: @internet Why? Each cell is surrounded by `\tabcolsep` space, so you get your width by dividing `\textwidth` by 3 and subtracting twice `\tabcolsep`.